# Como comparar instâncias de LocalTime?

Tags: java, data

Como faço para comparar duas variáveis de `LocalTime` no Java? Não consigo usar os padrões.

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public abstract class CorrespondenteBancario {

    private DayOfWeek diasDeFuncionamento[];
    private LocalTime horarioDeAbertura;
    private LocalTime horarioDeFechamento;


    public CorrespondenteBancario(DayOfWeek diasDeFuncionamento[], LocalTime abertura, LocalTime fechamento) {
        LocalTime horarioAtual = LocalTime.now();

        if (horarioAtual>abertura && horarioAtual<fechamento) {
            ...
        }
    }

    public void depositar(double umValor, ContaBancaria umaConta) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

No qual estou mandando um três parâmetros para outra classe chamada `CorrespondenteBancario`.

Answer (score 1):

A classe [`java.time.LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) possui os métodos [`isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#isBefore-java.time.LocalTime-) e [`isAfter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#isAfter-java.time.LocalTime-) para você comparar, respectivamente, se um horário ocorre antes e depois de outro.

Ou seja, em vez de fazer `t1 > t2`, você faz `t1.isAfter(t2)`, e em vez de usar `t1 < t2`, usa-se `t1.isBefore(t2)`:

```
public CorrespondenteBancario(DayOfWeek diasDeFuncionamento[], LocalTime abertura, LocalTime fechamento) {
    LocalTime horarioAtual = LocalTime.now();
    if (horarioAtual.isAfter(abertura) && horarioAtual.isBefore(fechamento)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Algumas linguagens permitem que se use operadores como `>` e `<` com instâncias de várias classes, mas não é o caso do Java.

---

Atenção, se quiser fazer a comparação `>=`, a lógica é um pouco diferente. Nesse caso ficaria:

```
if (! horarioAtual.isBefore(abertura) && ! horarioAtual.isAfter(fechamento)) {
    ...
}
```

Agora eu usei `! isBefore` (não é antes), o que significa que o horário pode ser depois, ou pode ser o mesmo horário (ou seja, maior ou igual). Não basta usar `isAfter` porque ele não verifica o caso em que são iguais. Uma lógica similar foi usada para `<=`, que se torna `! isAfter`.

---

Uma outra alternativa é usar [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#compareTo-java.time.LocalTime-), que retorna um valor negativo se o horário é menor que outro, zero caso sejam iguais, ou um valor positivo se o horário é maior que outro:

```
if (horarioAtual.compareTo(abertura) > 0 && horarioAtual.compareTo(fechamento) < 0) {
    ...
}
```

Mas nesse caso eu prefiro usar `isBefore` e `isAfter`, pois na minha opinião deixa o código mais claro e fácil de ler e entender (a única "vantagem" seria que fica mais fácil mudar o código acima para `>=` e `<=`).

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o CompareTo. Como no exemplo:

brightness_4
// Java program to demonstrate 
// LocalTime.compareTo() method

import java.time.*;

```
public class GFG { 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 

        // create a LocalTime Objects 
        LocalTime time1 
            = LocalTime.parse("17:52:49"); 
        LocalTime time2 
            = LocalTime.parse("13:08:00"); 

        // apply compareTo() 
        int value = time1.compareTo(time2); 

        // print LocalDateTime 
        System.out.println("Int Value:" + value); 

        if (value > 0) 
            System.out.println("LocalTime1 is greater"); 
        else if (value == 0) 
            System.out.println("LocalTime1 is equal to"
                               + " LocalTime2"); 
        else
            System.out.println("LocalTime2 is greater"); 
    } 
}
```